# Should page title tag be used for individual tabbed pages

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, seo

Google analytics detailed that users were currently viewing [my site](http://bigint.co.uk), but under the Active Page field Analytics was showing: Page Title: not set.

All my CSHTML file pages have titles, but it occurred to me that one CSHTML page (Web Services) is split into 7 individual tabbed pages with different content using Bootstrap 3 tabs, and the users could have be viewing one of those tabs.

After looking online I can't find anything about whether I should include a page title tag for each tab.

From an SEO perspective it would be great if I should be using page titles for each tab page because at the minute I am just summarising the content of all 7 pages under one page title.

Can anyone please accurately let me know what's best practice for use of the title tag on tabbed content?

***Update***

It looks like I have found an answer by researching the question from a different perspective.  The short answer looks to be that title tags are not needed on each tab because Google can't see the content.

On Search Engine Roundtable I found this article: Google: We Won't Index Dynamic Content Behind Tabs (Jul 27, 2015)

The relevant parts:

"In short, Google's John Mueller said several-months ago that Google won't index the content found within hidden tabs. But SEOs and Webmasters said they would. It might be more that they weight that content less than visible content.

Gary Illyes added that Google "won't see the content behind tabs if the content under the tab is dynamically generated (i.e. not just hidden)."

That means that when you click the tab, then the content first starts to be rendered, Google won't see it.  This question comes around using Bootstrap tabs to dynamically generated content in those tabs on click.

You can see what we (Google) see using Fetch as Google in Search Console (former Webmaster Tools); read more about the feature in our post titled Rendering pages with Fetch as Google."

Answer (score 0):

Do you use JQuery? You can change the title of a page at any time by:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.title = 'YourTitle';
});
```

Then again I don't know if google analytics works with this code. Could you verify this?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Yes, the tabs use jQuery.  But, I know how to add title tags.  I need to know whether I should be using a title tag for each individual tab.

Comment: I don't think so. since it only counts the core page I think

Comment: I concur.  I eventually found something on this by going about it differently - see above.  Thanks; your help is appreciated.